# Reuse UIButton style

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I've got a couple of UIButtons with all the same style, but sometimes they have different colors and sometimes they have different widths. However, I hate to make a seperate class for a new button that just needs a slightly different color, so I thought that there must be a way to style a button and take, for instance, the color and height as a property. After that I image it would work just as importing a UITableView's datasource/delegate.

So a more concrete question: is there a way to make a class for a UIButton that takes parameters such as width and height, and is it possible to declare this kind of class to a UIButton?

Comment: Just create little helper method in your class that creates the needed buttons. Pass in the color and width as parameters as needed.

Answer (score 0):

That's no problem at all. Create a category or subclass of `UIButton`. Define a custom init method like `- (instancetype)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size`. In the init method call `self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero]` and then set those properties on self.

Comment: You can't pass `nil` for a parameter that expects a `CGRect`.

Comment: Good catch. Changed to CGRectZero.

Answer (score 0):

About the frequently used style, you can make a method which return a styled button.

```
- (UIButton *)styledButtonWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return btn;
}
```

and you can create an instance of styledButton

```
UIButton *styledBtn = [self styledButtonWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
```

The second question, you can use category.

```
@interface UIView (BKExpansion)
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat frameX;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat frameHeight;
@end

@implementation UIView (BKExpansion)
- (CGFloat)frameX
{
    return self.frame.origin.x;
}

- (void)setFrameX:(CGFloat)frameX
{
    CGRect frame_ = self.frame;
    frame_.origin.x = frameX;
    self.frame = frame_;
}

- (CGFloat)frameWidth
{
    return self.frame.size.width;
}

- (void)setFrameWidth:(CGFloat)frameWidth
{
    CGRect frame_ = self.frame;
    frame_.size.width = frameWidth;
    self.frame = frame_;
}
@end
```

You can add frameY, frameBottom, and so on.

If you want to change frameX or frameWidth, just use

```
[styledBtn setFrameY:30];
```